# Animate Android Views to change their position and dimensions

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

Could you please suggest how it is possible to animate views in Android to change their position, width, height, margins, etc. I've attached picture with 3 views (colors - yellow, blue, orange) that located in viewgroup (green color), total number of viewgroups is 3. The idea is - when "Animate button" is clicked position and dimensions of viewgroups with their inner views should be changed with animation. Purple arrows show the two ways of animated direction.

[image]

Comment: go read this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation

Comment: You want it to transition within the same activity or transition through 2 different activity. This kind of transition can be automatically done by the `shared element transition` if you go from activity to activity. And for doing it inside an activity, manually create a transition. Read this blog: https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50

Comment: @TamHuynh, yes, I want to do it within the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by using `ConstraintLayouts` and `ConstraintSet` animations, for example : 
**layout_1.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout_1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="View1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="View2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="View3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/animateButton"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.88"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

layout_2.xml :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="View1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="View2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:text="View3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/animateButton"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.88"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and on the animateButton, you add :

```
 private fun addAnimation() {
    var set = false
    val constraint1 = ConstraintSet()
    constraint1.clone(root)
    val constraint2 = ConstraintSet()
    constraint2.clone(this, R.layout.layout_2)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.animateButton).setOnClickListener {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root)
        val constraint = if (set) constraint1 else constraint2
        constraint.applyTo(root)
        set = !set
    }
}
```

When we apply a new ConstraintSet to the same layout, ConstraintLayout will find the changes in constraints to elements with the same android:id and will animate properly. 
And of course, you can change the constraints of your items programatically if you don't want to duplicate a layout file.